# Verify if an object exist in a List

Tags: java, collections, comparator

What I need is: Verify if an object exist in a List comparing some attributes.

I'm in a trouble here with Collections and Comparator. I'm trying to do the verify with this Binary Search:

```
Collections.binarySearch(listFuncionarioObs2, formFuncionarioObsIns, formFuncionarioObsIns.objectComparator);//Binary search of an object in a List of this Object.
```

With this comparator:

```
public int compare(FuncionarioObs func, FuncionarioObs funcToCompare) {

    int testCodigo = -1;

    if(null != func2.getCodigo()){
        testCodigo = func.getCodigo().compareTo(funcToCompare.getCodigo());
    }

    int testData = func.getData().compareTo(funcToCompare.getData());
    int testEvento = func.getEvento().compareTo(funcToCompare.getEvento());
    int testAndamento = func.getAndamento().compareTo(funcToCompare.getAndamento());

    if(testCodigo == 0 && testData == 0 && testEvento == 0 && testAndamento == 0){
        return 0;
    }else if(testData == 0 && testEvento == 0 && testAndamento == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return -1;

}
```

But I'm a little bit lost, this is not working and I don't know the best way to do this. Someone can turn on a light for me?

Best regards,

Edited.

I'm sorting the List before the Binary Search with this code:

```
List<FuncionarioObs> listFuncionarioObsBD = funcionarioObsDAO.getFuncionarioObsById(sigla);
Collections.sort(listFuncionarioObsBD);
```

The comparator to the sort is:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(FuncionarioObs func) {

        if(this.getCodigo() > func.getCodigo()){
            return 1;
        }else if(this.getCodigo() == func.getCodigo() ) {
            return 0;
        }else{
            return -1;
        }

}
```

Comment: Is your list actually sorted / in order as per the order defined in your comparator?

Comment: Are you sure you want to return `-1` at the end of the method, or do you really want to return `testCodigo`?  Also: Why do you have the `if/else if` logic--the two branches are redundant.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I put the sort that I'm using before this comparator.... But It seems redundant too.. I don't know if the comparators are working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### CompareTo

Your compare wont work correctly. Right now it is only comparing the references of the objects. You will have to change this to compare the objects values:

```
@Override public int compareTo(Account aThat) {
final int BEFORE = -1;
final int EQUAL = 0;
final int AFTER = 1;

//this optimization is usually worthwhile, and can
//always be added
if (this == aThat) return EQUAL;

//primitive numbers follow this form
if (this.fAccountNumber < aThat.fAccountNumber) return BEFORE;
if (this.fAccountNumber > aThat.fAccountNumber) return AFTER;

//booleans follow this form
if (!this.fIsNewAccount && aThat.fIsNewAccount) return BEFORE;
if (this.fIsNewAccount && !aThat.fIsNewAccount) return AFTER;

.
.
.
//all comparisons have yielded equality
//verify that compareTo is consistent with equals (optional)
assert this.equals(aThat) : "compareTo inconsistent with equals.";

return EQUAL;
}
```

<sup>from [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10)</sup>

### Finding the object

Now comes the next part.
 As *CrtlAltDelete* has hinted it dependends of whether your list is sorted or not.
If its sorted ascending: iterate through the objects till you either find one which *compareTo* returns a Zero (== success) or a One ( == fail).

For an unsorted list you will have to iterate through all objects in search for one that returns a Zero.